# How to make a bridge egg in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft Hypixel Bed Wars, we have an item called Bridge Egg.  When thrown, it creates a bridge.

[image]

<sup>([source](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M2e8NKwWAz0/hqdefault.jpg))</sup>

Is it possible to make a bridge egg in vanilla Minecraft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, it is possible!

It is actually very easy to make a bridge egg in vanilla Minecraft.  To avoid unwanted chickens from spawning, *snowballs* are used in this post instead of eggs.  (That does not really make a difference.)

Think of it this way: we throw a snowball, and the snowball constantly place a block in its place.  This sounds so easy, so we place an always-active repeating command block, and type in:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] run setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:white_wool
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all.  The snowball placed a block in the player as soon as it is fired, and it crashes into the block.  We have to fix these problems.

The first problem is simple to fix: let the snowball place the block only if it is far enough away from the player.  This can be achieved with an `unless` clause:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] unless entity @a[distance=..3] run setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:white_wool
```

This way, at least the first block appears in *front* of the player, not inside.  But still, only one block is placed.  We can fix this issue by placing the block *beneath* the snowball instead of *in place* of it.  We replace `setblock ~ ~ ~` with `setblock ~ ~-2 ~`:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] unless entity @a[distance=..3] run setblock ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:white_wool
```

A (broken) bridge is appearing!  However, the bridge replaces everything (even the floor).  This is not desired.  We can add `keep` to the `setblock` command to make sure that it only places a block in an air block.

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] unless entity @a[distance=..3] run setblock ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:white_wool keep
```

Now we still have the broken bridge problem.  We fix it by using `fill ~ ~-2 ~ ~1 ~-2 ~1`, thus setting the width to 2 blocks:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:snowball] unless entity @a[distance=..3] run fill ~ ~-2 ~ ~1 ~-2 ~1 minecraft:white_wool keep
```

It's working fine:

[image]